# RTF Replace, wrong Colors

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox, xceed

i using the xceed richttextbox(es), load rtf Files inside the rtfbox and replacing in the Document the Placeholders with the formated text (using .Text  - works fine, but, if i change a color (RichTextBoxFormatBar) or add Text the colors of the inserted text are wrong (see picture)
what can it be?

Replace (simply replacing the [[$Text_****]] with the xceedrtf.Text):
daten_tmp is a String with the original RTF Mainfile)

```
daten_tmp   = daten_tmp.Replace(@"[[$Text_" + ((dynText)((Datenblock_Mitte_dynText)obj).cb_item).int_id + "]]", ((dynText)((Datenblock_Mitte_dynText)obj).cb_item).Text);

xceedrtf_Main.Text=daten_tmp;
```

[image]

Comment: just a guess: does the richtext you bind to the textbox already has colors defined in its rtf header. maybe the controls just do \highlight1 \highlight0 to highlight your text but 1 is defined as different colors than you would expect.

Comment: _what can it be?_ __Never__ change the Text property! __Only__ modify the SelectionXXX properties and/or the SelectedText after setting the selection via SelectionStart and SelectionLength! .

Comment: u mean copy&paste from a 2nd richtextbox?

Comment: Ok, i fixed it by using copy and paste with clipboard .. not a good solution (sometime the clipboard is blocked by a other application) but it works ...